# Syntax error because of order of selection

Tags: mysql

Is there any logical reason why this is a syntax error:

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF(dateA, dateB) as diff, *
FROM foo;
```

But this isn't:

```
SELECT 
*, DATEDIFF(dateA, dateB) as diff
FROM foo;
```

Or is it just because it is like it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is like it is, see [MySQL's documentation on select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), most notably:

> Use of an unqualified * with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified tbl_name.* reference
>
> SELECT AVG(score), t1.* FROM t1 ...